# Why does comparison between Int64 and Float32 give an unexpected answer?

Tags: julia

I'm using Julia version 1.6.2

```
julia> 2 < 1
false

julia> 2.0f32 < 1.0f32
false

julia> 2 < 1.0f32
true
```

Is this expected behavior? I don't understand what's going on here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason is that `32` is exponent value, so you have:

```
julia> Float32(1)
1.0f0

julia> big(1.0f32)
1.00000003318135351409612647563264e+32
```

and therefore:

```
julia> 1 == 1.0f32
false

julia> 1 == 1.0f0
true
```